# UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY Node.js NPM SFDX update command

Tags: node.js, npm, sfdx

Please help I am not able to do the sfdx update or login to the org using VS Code, Node.Js and NPM?

Note: I am behind a corporate firewall/proxy.

Error I am getting:

```
    C:\vijay\D Drive\Vijay\Learning\SFDC\Projects\VSCodeQuickstart> sfdx update sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... !
 Error: unable to get local issuer certificate Code: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY PS C:\vijay\D Drive\Vijay\Learning\SFDC\Projects\VSCodeQuickstart> sfdx force:auth:device:login 
ERROR running auth:device:login: request to login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried all the possible node commands strict ssl false, turn off proxy, registry command, referred almost 100s of forums for the answer.

Comment: PS C:\vijay\D Drive\Vijay\Learning\SFDC\Projects\VSCodeQuickstart> sfdx update
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... !
    Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    Code: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY      
PS C:\vijay\D Drive\Vijay\Learning\SFDC\Projects\VSCodeQuickstart> sfdx force:auth:device:login
ERROR running auth:device:login:  request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate